# how to combine multiple vectors into one while replacing elements in each vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

Say there is a data frame from a survey

```
race=Black   race=White   race=Hispanic
T            F            F
T            F            F
F            T            F
...
```

In this case, each column is a vector that can have the values `T` of `F`.
Also, the place of `T` in each vector will not overlap.
I want to combine this vector so that the result will be

```
column: race
Black
Black
White
...
```

Is there an easy way?

Comment: Are your values all of type `logical` ? If so, try `names(your_dataframe)[max.col(your_dataframe)]` Please share the output of `dput(head(your_dataframe))` if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate` and `case_when` from `dplyr` package.

First, load the package and your sample data:

```
library(dplyr)

zz <- "Black White Hispanic
1        T    F        F
2        T    F        F
3        F    T        F"

Mydata <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Assuming that your variables types are `logicals` you can run the following, as advised by @markus in the comments:

```
Mydata <- Mydata %>% 
            mutate(race = case_when(Black ~ "Black",
                                    White ~ "White",
                                    Hispanic ~ "Hispanic",
                                    TRUE ~ ""))
```

If your variables are `characters` with `string` values, then you can run

```
Mydata <- Mydata %>% 
            mutate(race = case_when(Black == "T" ~ "Black",
                                    White == "T" ~ "White",
                                    Hispanic == "T" ~ "Hispanic",
                                    TRUE ~ ""))
```

Comment: Your conditions can be simplified to `Black ~ "Black", White ~ "White"` etc. assuming that OP deals with logicals, like you do.